# C# Await in a delegate call

Tags: c#, .net, task, async-await

I have a function :

```
public async Task DoStuff()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

I need to call it from code running this:

```
list.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
{
    file.WriteAllBytes(reportPdf, data, () => **await** file.DoStuff());
};
```

But the `await` is not allowed in the Action `file.DoStuff` called in the above???

Comment: What is the signature for your `WriteAllBytes` method? (Basically, you need an async lambda expression, but it's not clear what the expected delegate type is.)

Comment: try `async () => await`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second lambda is not marked async

```
 list.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
 {
      file.WriteAllBytes(reportPdf, data, async () => await file.DoStuff());
 };
```

This depends on `file.WriteAllBytes()` allowing a `Func<Task>` to be passed in. An `Action` will not be enough.

Answer (score 3):

While [GazTheDestroyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193352/885318) is correct, there's no reason for the lambda expression to be marked `async` and to use an `await` since `file.DoStuff` already returns a `Task` and fits the `Func<Task>` delegate:

```
list.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
{
    file.WriteAllBytes(reportPdf, data, () => file.DoStuff());
};
```

It would also slightly improve performance since there's no reason to construct the state machine required for an `async-await` method/delegate.